# "This Suspense boundary received an update before it finished hydrating." Error when using suspense and dynamic import in Nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-suspense

I'm trying to lazy load a list of data with suspense and dynamic import in Nextjs. But getting following error:

```
Error: This Suspense boundary received an update before it finished hydrating. This caused the boundary to switch to client rendering. The usual way to fix this is to wrap the original update in startTransition.
```

I've tried using startTransition() but couldn't understand how to use it.

DataList.tsx:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

interface Props {
  data: any[];
}

const DataList = ({ data }: Props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {data &&
        data.map((item) => {
          return (
            <div key={item._id}> 
              {item.title} 
            </div>
          );
        })}
    </div>
  );
};
export default DataList;
```

DataPage.tsx

```js
import React, { Suspense, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
const DataList = dynamic(() => import("./DataList"), {
  suspense: true,
});

interface Props {}

const Projects = ({}: Props) => {

  const [data,setData] = useState<any[]>();

  useEffect( () => { 
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => setData(json))
  } , []) 

  return (
    <>
      <Suspense fallback={<p>LOADING</p>}>
        <DataList data={data} />
      </Suspense>
    </>
  );
};


export default DataPage;
```

Comment: Can you post the definition of `ProjectsList`?

Comment: Your code example is not even using `DataList` which is supposed to be imported dynamically.

Comment: @beig I have fixed it. You can check the code again.

Comment: This snippet isn't enough to reproduce the problem (I tried, it doesn't cause the error you report).

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm having the same problem

Comment: It's probabbly a bug in react you can see this isse here: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/25625, and PR: https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/25692

Comment: @Jalal This issue is still open it seems, although the PR is merged. Any idea on when this might get live

Comment: try updating your React to the latest it solves the issue. If you are updating a state inside the suspense boundary  then use `useTransition()`: https://beta.reactjs.org/apis/react/Suspense#preventing-already-revealed-content-from-hiding

Answer (score 0):

I guess sometimes this error appears without any possible error.

here is reference: https://www.reddit.com/r/nextjs/comments/yxa87v/im_glad_im_not_the_only_one_that_thinks_this/

Comment: Can you elaborate more? Why adding `ssr:false` will solve the transition issue?

Comment: @Jalal ```ssr : false``` is a flag that tells you that you are not importing a component at ```build time( server side import)```, but only for ```client side```

Answer (score 0):

use startTransition instead of useEffect !

I did this and my problem solved ...

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34781840)

Answer (score 0):

The error can sometimes appear when using Concurrent Mode features in React. If you're using Concurrent Mode in your application, it might introduce different rendering behaviors. Ensure you're using it correctly.

Here's a modified version of your code using startTransition to help prevent the error:

```
import React, { Suspense, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
const DataList = dynamic(() => import("./DataList"), {
  suspense: true,
});

interface Props {}

const Projects = ({}: Props) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState<any[]>();

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => {
        startTransition(() => {
          setData(json);
        });
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <Suspense fallback={<p>LOADING</p>}>
        <DataList data={data} />
      </Suspense>
    </>
  );
};

export default Projects;
```